# Convert JSON structure to dataframe in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data:

```py
d = {"a": {1.0: "this", 2.0: "that"}, "b": {1.0: "here", 2.0: "there"}}
```

How would one create dataframe:

```
  var  code   name
0   a   1.0   this
1   a   2.0   that
2   b   1.0   here
3   b   2.0  there
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use nested list comprehension for list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [(k, k1, v1) for k, v in d.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['var', 'code', 'name'])
print (df)
  var  code   name
0   a   1.0   this
1   a   2.0   that
2   b   1.0   here
3   b   2.0  there
```

Alternative solution with `DataFrame` constructor, [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(d)
        .rename_axis(index='code', columns='var')
        .unstack()
        .reset_index(name='name'))
print (df)
  var  code   name
0   a   1.0   this
1   a   2.0   that
2   b   1.0   here
3   b   2.0  there
```

Comment: Yess... A little trickier to generate a more representative input being a dict

Answer (score 2):

We can construct a dataframe from the dictionary, `stack` and `reset_index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).stack()
df.index =  df.index.set_names(['var', 'code'])
df.reset_index(name='name')
```

---

```
print(df)

   var code   name
0  1.0    a   this
1  1.0    b   here
2  2.0    a   that
3  2.0    b  there
```

Comment: thanks - this is nice but seems to be dependent on the values being 1,2?

Comment: Not really @baxx Stacking will create a multiindex, and by resetting the inedx `var` will just be set to whatever key the dictionary has. So IIUC it should be fine